# How to run executable file in AppDomain?

Tags: c#, executable, appdomain

I wanted to run an executable file in an AppDomain.
The execute file is not an assembly. 
How can i do that?
Can someone please tell me.

Answer (score 2):

An AppDomain, in the context of your question, is a .NET CLR concept and cannot be used to execute an unmanaged exectable.

If you run the executable using `Process.Start`, it will run in its own *Process* which has even higher isolation than an *AppDomain*.

What features of an AppDomain did you want to have when running the executable?

Comment: If the exe file will generate any exception then can the Process handle that?

Comment: Processes do not work that way, but processes have a return code which you can handle (`0` usually meaning success, anything else being application defined). However, the process will have ended at the point and no information can be passed between applications. If you need interprocess communication, you should look into named-pipe services (WCF supports them) or memory mapped files.

Comment: Yes i can get the ExitCode, but the what about the exception?? I mean to say the exception that is generated by the exe file is showing a dialogue box saying "SimulQuestion.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience." "Please tell Microsoft about the Problem", with "Send Error Report", "Don't send" button

Comment: That I don't know. I recommend asking a second question for it.

Answer (score 0):

What about `Proces.Start(Your exe)` ? Is that not working?

Comment: But i want to achieve the benefits that AppDomain provides.

Comment: Sorry, i dint get you? can you be some more specific?

Comment: It should run separately, should not interact with other resources. It should not interact with other process and should run in a virtual boundary.

Comment: @Dev: Running it using Process.Start will run it as different PROCESS - It would run separately, wouldn't interact with anything (except the OS) and would be a completely separate application.

Comment: How can i set rules to that process? E.g: It should not write / delete anything from the hard-disk.